# Is the shortened MSBuild format compatible with older .NET versions?

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

MSBuild files used at the time of Visual Studio 2017 can be drastically shortened compared to previous versions. As is explained e.g. [in a blogpost](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/iblogger/2017/04/05/easily-supporting-multiple-target-frameworks-tfms-with-vs2017-and-nuget/):

> A lot of the boilerplate configuration was removed in order to make the MSBuild format clean and readable.

Indeed, when you create a new .NET Standard project, the resulting `.csproj` file only contains a couple of lines by default:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

When creating a normal .NET Framework project in the same VS, though, the `.csproj` file will still be as long as previously, featuring several `<PropertyGroup>` and `<ItemGroup>` elements, references to some default BCL assemblies, definitions of debug settings, etc.

A superficial test by editing the shortened source code by hand to target e.g. .NET Framework 2.0 did not appear to lead to any issues (at least, not error messages). Still, I now wonder: **Can the shortened MSBuild format be used to target other/older framework versions than .NET Standard?**

Comment: It is not that simple, the project type matters a lot.  A project file can contain elements that matter to msbuild for a specific project item and elements that matter to the IDE.  Stuff like SubType, DependentUpon, DesignTime, HintPath, Content, Generator.  So fuggedaboudid for Winforms, WPF and Store apps.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ok, maybe my question sounded a bit too absolute. I am ok with adding references, item groups, and file-by-file includes with elements like SubType, DependentUpon, etc., in order to support e.g. compilation of WPF files - if only I can forego the explicit definition of property groups for Debug and Release builds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can taret any supported platform with this syntax. It only gives you a few additional defaults.

However, some features may be missing - like designer support for classic EF, ASP.NET and WPF. While these projects should compile, you may have some difficulties and need custom msbuild hacks to make them work.

But if you are just writing libraries, console applications / windows services, you should be fine.

If you want to compile using the `dotnet` CLI, you need to target at least .NET 4. If you target a lower version, e.g. `net35` the project will only compile using msbuild from the developer command prompt on windows or mono's msbuild.

Even for portable targets, a few workarounds exist. For example, Netwonsoft.Json recently moved from a complex setup of multiple csproj and sln files with shared c# source files to a [single consolidated csproj file that multitargets to many frameworks](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/6057d9b83126315e441711b5672776f36bdc3afa/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj).

Comment: "custom msbuild hacks" - by that, do you mean adding `<Compile>` elements (or similar, with their respective sub-elements) for a couple of files that need special treatment, or anything more cumbersome? "If you want to compile using the dotnet CLI (...) the project will only compile using msbuild" - actually, I wasn't even aware there are these two options so far. But what's the implication - is there any problem with compiling by means of `msbuild` with respect to the matter at hand, or do some target frameworks only compile with one, some only with the other command?

Comment: 1. to compile for .net < 4, msbuild needs to use the local 2.* CLR, which isn't available in .NET Core.
2. mostly making sure the `DependentUpon` metadata is set correctly so you get nested .cs files under xaml files.

Comment: 1. That means I restrict the set of environments that can build my sources, while extending the set of environments that can later on execute my assemblies? If so, that sounds ok to me. 2. That, too, sounds feasibe, and still quite a bit better than maintaining several parallel project files for different target frameworks.